# JFace wizard question

Tags: swt, jface

I am a developing a RCP application. It has a wizard. It has four wizard pages. I am intending to run a DB query when I click on "Next" button in my first page and load the results in second page. In the second page, user will select one of the query returned object. It will run another DB query and update the third page. I somehow managed to run the query in my first page "getNextPage" function. In the second page, I dont know how to load the results. There is a createControl() method and I thought of updating the second page by adding the code. But it will get called when the wizard is created and not when "Next" button is clicked. Can someone tell me whether this is possible. Thaks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to override the setVisible() method of the second wizard page and populate the UI when visible==true